# FaceTime refuses to provide video, "poor network"

Tags: network, wifi, facetime

In my house on WiFi users of iphones, MBPs and MBAs all have this problem where FaceTime goes audio-only and complains "poor network connection".

It happens often, but not always.

Speed tests demonstrate results exactly as expected -- 200 down, 8 up, good ping and jitter figures.  Upload speed isn't awesome but it's far more than what FT needs and it's what my provider provides.

NO OTHER APP has this problem.  Zoom, Microsoft Teams, Google Meet, and Whatsapp Video are all used frequently and successfully. 4k TVs have no issues either, fwiw. But FaceTime fails frequently on all devices.

Comment: It could be a QoS issue with the router. We'd need to know the model to be more specific. See https://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/ for a general guide.

Comment: It's an Asus router with Qos set to Adaptive/Work-from-Home.